# why Nodemon couldn't find the path to run its script

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I'm working on chat application , I'm using express , socket.io, moment and nodemon.
If I run `nodemon server.js` it works, but if I want to run my script as follow `npm run dev`
and this is inside my package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1"
  }


"scripts": {
    "dev" : "nodemon server.js"
  }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
'...\ChatApp-Rooms\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Sam Taklimi\Desktop\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
```

for some reason the path of my nodemon is not correct.
Following stack overflow, in PowerShell I changed

```
ExecutionPolicy to 
Unrestricted
```

still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install nodemon as dependency of your project like that

`npm i nodemon`

When you run nodemon from your terminal you run a package that is probably installed globally. When you run it as part of your npm scripts you need to run it from the installed dependencies of your project

Comment: already done that , its not the issue

Comment: @SamTaklimi can you share the structure of your project (files and directories)

Comment: this the folder directory :
C:\Users\Sam Taklimi\Desktop\D&D\ChatApp

Answer (score 0):

Your server.js has to be in the same path/dir/level with your package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the package with npx?

```
npx nodemon server.js
```

If nodmeon isn't installed globally with npm -g, it could be that its having trouble locating the package. Running with npx will prevent the need for a global installation